# Downloading an MP3 - WGET works, CURL doesn't

Tags: html, curl, mp3, wget

I have been using WGET to download the following file:

```
wget http://www.fsnradionews.com/FSNNews/FSNHeadlines.mp3
```

This works perfectly but I want to do the same thing using CURL. If I use:

```
curl -L -O http://www.fsnradionews.com/FSNNews/FSNHeadlines.mp3
```

..the file downloads BUT rather than being the audio file, it contains the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Having researched the problem, many have suggested the request is being redirected hence why I added the -L, but this doesn’t appear the fix the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the server is not accepting the User-Agent. You can supply a common user agent like `Mozilla/4.0` with the `-A` option in curl. The final command would become:

```
curl -O http://www.fsnradionews.com/FSNNews/FSNHeadlines.mp3 -A "Mozilla/4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
curl http://www.fsnradionews.com/FSNNews/FSNHeadlines.mp3 -o FSNHeadlines.mp3
```

?

Should download the file from `http://www.fsnradionews.com/FSNNews/FSNHeadlines.mp3` and save it as `FSNHeadlines.mp3`.

Comment: This still gives the same problem, you can run the command yourself to see it